# Adapting to a constantly changing model Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, class, initialization

```
class User {
    var uid : String
    var profileImageURL : String

    init(uid : String, profileImageURL : String) {
        self.uid = uid 
        self.profileImageURL = profileImageURL
    }
}
```

If my project were to start out with a User model such as the one above, and I have a huge-scaled application where this User is being initialized in over 20 files, if I were to go in and add a new required property such as age, I would have to fix my initializers for every single file. Worse off, I would have to go in after each initializer and set the new property on its own line.

If I were required to add in 25 new properties over the course of production, this would be a nightmare.

What is the best way to handle large models like this that might change in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something  like this

```
class User {

    var uid : String
    var profileImageURL : String

    init(all : [String:Any]) {
        self.uid = all["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        self.profileImageURL = all["profileImageURL"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

or write a Codable class to decode the dictionary directly

Answer (score 2):

I would not initialise an object in 20+ location. That makes the code fragile. Put an extra layer like user management where you can ask the current user / ask for any user. And make the init there, in one single place.